# julia executable path in vscode on windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, julia

I am trying to get Julia to run on VSCode on windows. I cannot get julia Language server to run. The executable path = "C:\Julia-1.1.1\bin\" which is the correct path. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the parameter's description, the path should point to the julia executable. You need to add `julia.exe` to the end.

```
C:\Julia-1.1.1\bin\julia.exe
```

If you are editing the JSON file directly, you will need to escape the backslashes.

```
C:\\Julia-1.1.1\\bin\\julia.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The following setting works for me, without the .exe extension.

```
"julia.executablePath": "C:\\Users\\...\\Julia-1.3.0\\bin\\julia"
```