# Unable to figure out the Julia executable path

Tags: julia, vscode-extensions, macos-monterey

I have seen a lot of questions on this topic already but my problem is that I am not able to figure out where `Julia.exe` even exists (as the answer indicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56841562/julia-executable-path-in-vscode-on-windows)). I can see all the files with `.py` extension but none with `.exe`. I have installed Julia twice already. I am using M1 macOS and I am very unsure as to what am I supposed to even mention in this path.

I tried entering `./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages` but it did not work out. I tried `whereis Julia` on terminal but it did not work out either. I got no output for this.

Comment: Isn't Julia.exe and Windows executable... but you say you're on MacOS ??????

Comment: Another thing: did you install Julia using anaconda? If so, that's not recommended. If not, then why would the Julia executable be in the anaconda/python directory? Julia is not a Python package...

Comment: I think you'd have better luck typing `where julia` (note the lower-case 'j').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your question - you say you are using a Mac M1 with MacOS, yet you are trying to locate a `julia.exe` file, which only exists for a Windows installation.

Have you followed the [installation instructions for macOS](https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/#macos) on the Julia website? Quoting from there:

> On macOS, a julia-1.8.5-mac64.dmg file is provided, which contains Julia-1.8.app. Installation is the same as any other Mac software: drag the Julia-1.8.app to Applications Folder's Shortcut. The Julia download runs on macOS 10.9 Mavericks and later releases. You can build from source for macOS 10.6 Snow Leopard (possibly earlier versions as well) and 32-bit but neither are fully supported.

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows

```
> where julia
c:\Julia-1.9.0-beta4\bin\julia.exe
```

#### Linux / OSX

```
$ whereis julia
julia: /usr/bin/julia
```

#### Julia

```
julia> Base.julia_cmd()
`'c:\Julia-1.9.0-beta4\bin\julia.exe' -Cnative '-Jc:\Julia-1.9.0-beta4\lib\julia\sys.dll' -g1`

julia> Base.julia_cmd()[1]
"c:\\Julia-1.9.0-beta4\\bin\\julia.exe"
```

#### Via Julia interpreter from command line (works both on Linux and Windows):

```
> julia -e "println(Base.julia_cmd()[1])"
c:\Julia-1.9.0-beta4\bin\julia.exe
```